Connecting 1” PVC to 1/2” PEX
We have a 1 inch PVC pipe going under the ground from the well, and sticks out near the house. I don’t know the technical term but I call it a spicket. You turn the handle and water shoots out.
We have 1/2 inch blue PEX pipe for the house. I can’t find a 1x1/2 PVC to PEX fitting, and I was wondering if that’s because we aren’t supposed to do that.
This is the main water pipe for the house. We were going to run the blue PEX from it to the toilet so my mom can finally have a toilet with running water inside the house and possibly her bathroom sink so she can get fresh water.

There is no reason why you cannot connect the two.  Any combination of adapters that mate will do, and the most common adapters you can use will have pipe threads as the mating fitting.  The first adapter must have one end 1" PVC slip, and the other adapter one end 1/2" PEX.  For example:

1" PVC slip to 3/4" male NPT (threaded pipe) + 3/4" female NPT (threaded pipe) to 1/2" PEX
1" PVC slip to 1/2" male NPT (threaded pipe) + 1/2" female NPT (threaded pipe) to 1/2" PEX
1" PVC slip to 3/4" female NPT (threaded pipe) + 3/4" male NPT (threaded pipe) to 1/2" PEX (this is the least preferable in that it uses PVC for the female threaded connection.  Female PVC is more likely to crack under stress than male PVC.  The PEX fittings are metal and thus better suited for use as the female part.)

Other combinations that fit together - even if it takes a third or fourth intermediary part - will work.

The product you are looking for is called "shark-bite" and easiest way to connect pipes. Requires no special tools to install on hot or cold water lines

Does sharkbite make a 1" to 1/2" transition?

Sharkbite fittings are not certified for use with PVC.  They are certified for use with Copper, CPVC and PEX yes.  PVC , No.

@ Matthew,  They do make a1" to 1/2" transition and a 1"/ 1" 1/2"  T.  However that 1" relates to copper and cpvc sizing and not PVC.   PVC is not used in home potable water supply plumbing in the house.  Irrigation outside and supply to the house yes.
